# How can I call box.commit from python client

Tags: python, transactions, tarantool

I want to execute some code in single transaction.
I use tarantool 1.6 with python client (0.5.4) 
My code looks like this (it does'not work):

```
import tarantool
tnt = tarantool.Connection(**params)
tnt.call('box.begin')
tnt.update(space1, 1, [('=', 2, 100)])
tnt.update(space2, 1, [('+', 1, 200)])
tnt.call('box.comit')
```

I got error:

```
tarantool.error.DatabaseError: (33, "Procedure 'box.comit' is not defined")
```

What's wrong? How can I call box.comit from python?

Comment: Should that be `box.commit`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I make small mistaske in code, this variant works fine:

```
import tarantool
tnt = tarantool.Connection(**params)
tnt.call('box.begin')
tnt.update(space1, 1, [('=', 2, 100)])
tnt.update(space2, 1, [('+', 1, 200)])
tnt.call('box.commit')
```

Comment: Use stored procedure instead of this.
`function my_update(space_1_tuple, space_2_table)
  box.begin()
  box.space.space1.update{space_1_tuple ...}
  -- and so on
  box.comit()
end`